# Intelij - Run in parallel

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, intellij-idea, ide

I have the latest version of intelij and I want to run my app in parallel but I can't.

> 'Client' is not allowed to run in parallel.
> Would you like to stop the running one?

I checked the tutorials and each one says that you need to select options in run, edit configuration.

But when I open the edit configuration menu, I have no options "run in parallel".

My view on configuration

[image]

Can someone help me? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Select `Allow multiple instances` in the `Modify options` dropdown menu.

[image: Run/Debug Configuration]